# Combine columns into one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a client db and return an address db record with this statement:

```
$query = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT company, street, etc. FROM clients ');
```

The result looks like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
            [company] => The one and only company 
            [street] => Road to heaven 114
            [etc.] => ....
  [1] => Array ( 
            [company] => Better forever
            [street] => Wild west 145 
            [etc.] => ....
       )
    )
```

For a quick overview I generate a php table and print a combined string from `company, street, etc.` into one field.

---

To make it more simple in php I want to let the job be done by `mySQL`.
The PDO prepare statement looks like this:

```
$query = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT company +", "+ street as adress  FROM clients ');
```

But the result contains weired numbers, not what I expected.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
            [adress] => 0 
        )
  [1] => Array ( 
            [adress] => 6 
       )
  [2] => Array ( 
            [adress] => 15 
       )
    )
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: My question is not about "Can I concatenate rows ... ?" but the form how to do it. The answer is given perfectly from Oldskool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `+` to concatenate different fields, as it will then become a mathematical expression. `+` is the arithmetic operator for [addition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus), that's why it is returning numbers.

You're looking for the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) (or alternatively the CONCAT_WS) function, like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`company`, ", ", `street`) AS `address` FROM `clients`;
```

That should return:

```
['address'] => 'The one and only company, Road to heaven 114'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','company','street') AS  `address`  FROM  `clients`;
```

The first argument is the separator for the rest of the argument

Comment: The first argument is the separator for the rest of the argument